linear mixed effects models (lme): model comparison via AIC() or anova() function
I have a quick question concerning model selection for linear mixed effects models: When directly comparing AICs of two models (either including or excluding an additional fixed effect) versus comparing two models with the anova() function in R, I get opposite results regarding the better model (when the outcome variable is log-transformed due to heteroskedasticity). In addition, the AIC values that are shown through the anova() function for both models differ from the AIC values directly obtained for both models through the AIC() function (which is true also when not log-transforming the dependent variable). Is it because both functions calculate these values differently or is there another explanation? I would be very grateful for a hint. Many thanks in advance!
I tried the anova() and AIC() functions without log-transforming the dependent variable, too. This time, both approaches revealed the same model to be better but the specific AIC values still differed between both functions.

Which package are you using? It would be helpful to see some code.

@Roland
The models with simplified factor names would be:
base_model<-lmer(Rating ~ 1 + Factor1Factor2 + (Factor1 | Item) + (Factor2 | Participant), data = my_data);
model_2<-lmer(Rating ~ 1 + Factor1Factor2 + Factor3 + (Factor1 | Item) + (Factor2 | Participant), data = my_data);
The codes I used to compare both models:
anova(base_model, model_2);
AIC(base_model);
AIC(model_2);
packages used: lme4, lmerTest, AICcmodavg (this one also provides slightly different AICs since corr. f. smaller samples but overall similar to AIC(), whereas anova() provides rather different AICs)

I think I have actually found the answer (something similar being discussed here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2013q4/021302.html): For the AIC() function, REML = FALSE is not automatically set. Setting it manually, both functions reveal the same AIC values for the respective models.
